# How to open an image editor window and display an image file in it?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, image, uv-image-editor

I'm looking to open a new image editor window and display a new image from a file in it -- all via python script. What is the best way to do this? Searched but only found how to load and display an image, but not how to do it in a separate window. Thanks.

Comment: By separate window do you mean a floating window torn away from the rest of the program interface, or do you mean dividing an existing editor and changing to an image editor? Tear away can still be done by holding shift while pulling the top corner I believe.

Comment: floating window where you can view and save the image

Comment: Related: [How do I get a popup UV Image Editor and force it to show the Active Paint Slot?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94109/31447) Also, what did you find exactly? What exactly does not work? Please add that to your question and show some effort *(just trying to help making this question better, according to [How to ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)...)*.

Comment: Well, I already looked at the link you showed and realized it's not an image_editor with all the bells and whistles-- and I need to have the ability to save the image. I searched here and on BlendDev and on BA and Reddit and didn't find anything I could use.

My take is it's not that easy to do, so I'll try and work around this. Turns out learning Python is the easy part-- learning the Blender API is much harder! haha

Comment: I'm getting [an image editor in a seperate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YKaL.png) from my old answer linked above (with all the bells and whistles). Isn't that what you want actually? In case you're rendering anything before you can just call `bpy.ops.render.view_show("INVOKE_DEFAULT")` to open up the render window. Please elaborate on your goal and add more information to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Blender does not support creating a new window officially.* However, there are [some workarounds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81974/31447).

#### [bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show)

One way is to open up a new *User Preferences* window and change its [Area.type](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type) to `'IMAGE_EDITOR'` using [`bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show) operator:

```
# Call user prefs window
bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
# Change area type
area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.areas[0]
area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
```

#### [bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli)

Another way is using [`bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli), which creates a new window from a specific area of your screen. Find an area of interest, store the [Area.type](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type), set it to `'IMAGE_EDITOR'` call the the opeator and reset the area:

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

# Iterate through the areas
for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type in ('IMAGE_EDITOR', 'VIEW_3D', 'NODE_EDITOR'):
        old_area = area.type        # Store current area type
        area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'  # Set the area to the Image editor
        with context.temp_override(area=area):  # Override the area member
            bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        area.type = old_area        # Restore the old area
        break
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
# Copy context member
context = bpy.context.copy()

# Iterate through the areas
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type in ('IMAGE_EDITOR', 'VIEW_3D', 'NODE_EDITOR'):
        old_area = area.type        # Store current area type
        area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'  # Set the area to the Image editor
        context['area'] = area      # Override the area member
        bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli(context, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        area.type = old_area        # Restore the old area
        break
```

#### Assigning the image

In order to display an image in that window, just load an image and assign its data block it to [`SpaceImageEditor.image`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.html#bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.image) eg using the active space: `bpy.context.area.spaces.active.image = image`. Complete example using the code to generate an image from: [Is it possible to create image data and save to a file from a script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/652/31447):

[image]

```
size = 640, 480
image = bpy.data.images.new("MyImage", width=size[0], height=size[1])

pixels = [None] * size[0] * size[1]
for x in range(size[0]):
    for y in range(size[1]):
        # assign RGBA to something useful
        r = x / size[0]
        g = y / size[1]
        b = (1 - r) * g
        a = 1.0

        pixels[(y * size[0]) + x] = [r, g, b, a]

pixels = [chan for px in pixels for chan in px]
image.pixels = pixels

# Call user prefs window
bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
# Change area type
area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.areas[0]
area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

# Assign the image
bpy.context.area.spaces.active.image = image
```

**Note:** [`bpy.ops.render.view_show("INVOKE_DEFAULT")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.view_show) might be interesting as well.

Comment: Thanks brockmann! :-)

Comment: Shot in the dark, glad this helps though. FYI: In case you didn't read my comment above, updated my old operator on [How do I get a popup UV Image Editor and force it to show the Active Paint Slot?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94099/how-do-i-get-a-popup-uv-image-editor-and-force-it-to-show-the-active-paint-slot/94109#94109) for you, had to change the icon to make it work out ouf the box in Blender 2.8x... @chippwalters

Comment: Is there any way to place image editor window in specific place when opens?

Comment: Pops up where your mouse cursor is. Suggest ask a new question referring to this one @SimonetosTheGreek

Comment: Thank you @brockmann I will!!! :)