# How to Create the UV Grid Texture with Python?

Tags: python, texturing, uv

How to create the generated "UV Grid" texture with the help of the Blender Python API?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either [generate a checkerboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169478/how-to-make-a-checkerboard-in-numpy) and [assign the pixels to a new image data block](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/652/31447) or just call [`bpy.ops.image.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.image.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20image%20new#bpy.ops.image.new) and pass `UV_GRID`:

[image]

One downside of using the operator is that you would have to supply a reliable (unique) name for the image data block otherwise it automatically gets renamed to `Untitled.001`, `Untitled.002`... due to Blender's nature of handling data:

```
import bpy
import secrets

# Generate "unique" name
image_name = secrets.token_hex(5)

# Call the operator 
bpy.ops.image.new(
        name=image_name, 
        width=1024, 
        height=1024, 
        color=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
        alpha=True, 
        generated_type='UV_GRID', # BLANK, COLOR_GRID
        float=False, 
        use_stereo_3d=False, 
        tiled=False
    )

# Get the image from data blocks
image = bpy.data.images.get(image_name)

# Display the result
if image:
    bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    # Change area type
    area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.areas[0]
    area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

    # Assign the image
    bpy.context.area.spaces.active.image = image
```

Related:

- [Is it possible to create image data and save to a file from a script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/643/is-it-possible-to-create-image-data-and-save-to-a-file-from-a-script/652#652)
- [How to open an image editor window and display an image file in it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/175790/31447)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to create a new image containing the "UV Grid" or the "Color Grid" directly, without using the `bpy.ops.image.new(...)` operator:

```
import bpy

# Create the image
img = bpy.data.images.new(
        name='some name',
        width=1024,
        height=1024,
        # Further arguments are optional and this are the defaults:
        alpha=False,
        float_buffer=False,
        stereo3d=False,
        is_data=False,
        tiled=False
    )

# Setup the grid
img.source = 'GENERATED'  # optional, since it's done implicitly
img.generated_type = 'UV_GRID'  # alternatively use 'COLOR_GRID' here
```