# How to switch image via python?

Tags: python

I want to switch from `Render Result` to `Viewer Node` via python.

[image]

Comment: It only works in the current context

Comment: It works if you have any of the visible areas with the Image editor, which should be the case in most contexts. If you don't have one, you can always make one. See [python - How to open an image editor window and display an image file in it? - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175790/how-to-open-an-image-editor-window-and-display-an-image-file-in-it)

Comment: If none of this answers to your question, then please edit your post to better explain what you need.